# In jetpack compse Is it a good idea to put shared screens in a separate graph when navigating across nested navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a home graph with a bottom navigation bar, a search graph, a shopping cart graph, and a productList screen shared between the home graph and the search graph. I also have a productDetails screen that must be accessible from all other graphs.

I am having problems navigating across different screens that belong to different graphs in Jetpack Compose. When I try to access a screen outside the graph, I get the error "ViewModelStore should be set before setGraph call".

my question is it practical to put productDetails screen and productList screen in two separate navGraph ?